# Hartl Chapter Error Before 9.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundle

I'm going through Mr. Hartl's Tutorial and trying to copy it exactly, even kinda using his completed github code as a guide, but I'm stuck with the following after running the "bundle exec rspec spec/":

Failures:

```
  1) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user }
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:19:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user }
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:19:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user }
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:19:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user }
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:19:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user }
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:19:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Authentication signin with valid information followed by signout 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user }
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:19:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) User pages profile page signup with valid information after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) User pages profile page signup with valid information after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  9) User pages profile page signup with valid information after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  10) User pages profile page with invalid information 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Save changes" }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find button "Save changes"
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:76:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  11) User pages profile page page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
       expected #has_content?("Update your profile") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:70:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  12) User pages profile page page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title("Edit user") }
       expected #has_title?("Edit user") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  13) User pages profile page page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
       expected #has_link?("change", {:href=>"http://gravatar.com/emails"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:72:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.83 seconds
53 examples, 13 failures
```

spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do

    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Sign in" }

        it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

        describe "after visiting another page" do
          before { click_link "Home" }
          it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
        end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "after submission" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_title('Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do

      before do
        fill_in "Name", with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
      end
    end
  end

    describe "edit" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
    end

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
      it { should have_title("Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

app/views/users/edit.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm kind of a greenhorn at this, so let me know if you would like to inspect any of my other codes.

Added to the post, spec/support/utilities.rb:

```
include ApplicationHelper

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
  match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')
  end
end

def sign_in(user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Sign in when not using Capybara.
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

Added app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

app/views/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I reverted some of the code to the following excerpt from previous tutorials to sessions_controller.rb:

```
.
.
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
.
.
```

It resulted in only 7 errors this time around.

```
Failures:

  1) User pages profile page signup with valid information after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0xa6de278>
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `index'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages profile page signup with valid information after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0xa6de278>
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `index'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages profile page signup with valid information after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0xa6de278>
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `index'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User pages profile page with invalid information 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Save changes" }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find button "Save changes"
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:76:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) User pages profile page page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
       expected #has_content?("Update your profile") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:70:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) User pages profile page page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title("Edit user") }
       expected #has_title?("Edit user") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) User pages profile page page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
       expected #has_link?("change", {:href=>"http://gravatar.com/emails"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:72:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.88 seconds
53 examples, 7 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:57 # User pages profile page signup with valid information after saving the user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:58 # User pages profile page signup with valid information after saving the user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:59 # User pages profile page signup with valid information after saving the user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:78 # User pages profile page with invalid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:70 # User pages profile page page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:71 # User pages profile page page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:72 # User pages profile page page
```

Comment: Well, if you look at your first set of errors, they all occurred at `signin_user`, so sharing that code would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I included utilities.rb, if that's the pertinent code.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the problem is with visiting `signin_path`, so look at (or share) your routes (e.g. with `rake routes`) and share the code for the method for GET of `signin_path`

Comment: for rake routes, I get <code>signin GET    /signin(.:format)         sessions#new</code>

Comment: I'm not sure what `code` is in that context, but it looks like you need to share your `sessions_controller.rb` file

Comment: added the <!-- app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb --> file Thanks for the patience as I try to master stackoverflow code as well

Comment: No problem. Ok, you can see that the `new` controller method doesn't do anything, so Rails will be looking for `views/sessions/new.html.erb` file. What do you have there?

Comment: Added the views/sessions/new.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with your `Sessions#create` method:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I suspect you you are ending up where you have the comment, at which point it "falls through" to the Rails standard controller code which then looks for the `create` sessions view corresponding to this being the `create` controller method.

If you check out the corresponding code in the Hartl github repository, its:

```
  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                             params[:session][:password])
    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    end
  end
```

As to how you got there, it appears that the `sign_in user` method was successful in getting to and through your Sessions `new` controller and view code.  The `submit` in your view took you to the Sessions#create point.

Comment: I know this is counterintuitive, but Hartl does change the code to the bottom code later on in the chapter, in 9.19, but not before changing a bunch of other codes to suit that change. I know it's the ideal code to have in there, but it might not work yet and I'm just trying to slog through the tutorial in the correct order. I plugged in that new code and got 16 errors. Thanks for your help BTW.

Comment: At least in the current version of the tutorial the code you're missing is introduced in section 8.2 in Listing 8.13 at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-sign_in_success_not_yet_working

Comment: Reverted some of the code from earlier Hartl and only got 7 errors.

Comment: Did you see my earlier comment about listing 8.13?

Comment: Have you been following the tutorial and passing all along?

Comment: Yes, I've been passing all along, and I plugged in the code from 8.13, as shown above.

Comment: Sorry for belaboring this, but if you've been following the tutorial and been passing all along, how is that the code from listing 8.13 was missing given that you're now in Chapter 9?

Comment: Also, the errors you are getting are from your code calling `paginate`, but the use of `paginate` isn't introduced until 9.3.3

Comment: That is a solid point. While I have had passing all along, there have been more hiccups lately, so a combination of adapting Hartl's code, along with stackoverflow code that I may have borrowed as well, well maybe, I should go back a few chapters. I appreciate your patience and your tutelage, but perhaps I should go back to first grade with this.

Comment: A _lot_ of people have taken that tutorial and it really is well done. The key is to follow the instructions to the letter and never move on until you've resolved any discrepancies.

Comment: And I would say _never_ grab code from the github repository or from further ahead.  You're just asking for trouble.

Comment: One more thing. It's customary to upvote any answers you find helpful and to ultimately accept one if it has satisfactorily answered your question. This kind of extensive, interactive support, moving from one symptom to the next is not the norm, although occasionally you'll find someone willing to do it, as in this case (at least so far).

Comment: I thank you. I would totally upvote this (and you), but my reputation is too low.

Comment: Hey, you just tripled your reputation! :-) If you keep up that geometric rate, you'll be ahead of Jon Skeet in no time. ;-)